# How to create a convex glass effect using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, image-editing

I have a picture of a chessboard and I want to add convex glass above it.. I am attaching an examples here

https://www.shutterstock.com/image-vector/vector-modern-transparent-circle-glass-plate-757157002

[image]

How can I create a convex glass effect using Photoshop?

Comment: Spherize filter?

Answer (score 2):

Painting a piece of glass into a photo is difficult. The subject has been up several times as different incarnations and they have got numerous answers.

Text "a convex piece of glass in front of a chessboard" offers quite wide range of possibilities. That can mean you have something like a cheese dome. Drawing it is very difficult if you don't want anything which looks a separate partially transparent layer, but something which really looks like it was there when the chessboard was photographed. A much easier option is to think "it's a looking glass". The next example shows one:

[image]

The chessboard here is captured from an ad which offers a premium chess kit with a glossy wooden board.

1. A circular selection is made, copied and pasted to a new layer.
2. The copy is distorted. One comment suggests filter Spherize. It pushes image towards the edge of the selection and creates an illusion of not so high quality enlarging. Spherize is applied twice to make the edge really badly deformed. The selection is ON in both times.
3. The distorted copy has got a slight brightness reduction to simulate light absorbtion in low quality lenses.
4. The distorted copy got layer style Bevel&Emboss. It makes the dark zone up and bright gloss to the bottom. It doesn't affect in the middle.

This one doesn't have other light effects. The glosses of the chessboard are luckily spherized so that there's no need to paint reflections from (imagined) environment to the glass.

I said luckily. I avoided the test which separates who has some real talent and who is only a soldier of fortune.

If you search older question search also for glass bottles and spheres.